# Unknown register name "q0" in asm (arm64)

Tags: ios, llvm, xcode5, neon, arm64

I'm currently trying to compile my lib for the new arm64 arch. I have a bunch of NEON assembly and for all of them I receive an error

> Unknown register name "q0" in asm.

Even if I write smth simple as this:

```
asm (
     ""
     :
     :
     : "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3"
     );
```

I thought arm64 supports NEON. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“v0”:

```
scanon$ cat bar.c
int foo(void) {
  __asm__("":::"q0");
  return 0;
}
scanon$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang bar.c -arch arm64 -c
bar.c:2:16: error: unknown register name 'q0' in asm
  __asm__("":::"q0");
               ^
1 error generated.
scanon$ cat foo.c
int foo(void) {
  __asm__("":::"v0");
  return 0;
}
scanon$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang foo.c -arch arm64 -c
scanon$
```

arm64 is a new ISA.  The actual NEON instructions and register layout are entirely new.  You will need to re-write or adapt assembly code for the new architecture.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are compiling and the full error message.  As I noted, however, arm32 assembly will need to be heavily modified for arm64.

Comment: I've already did that. An empty asm with clobber list and the error is Unknown register name “q0” in asm

Comment: … and if you use “v0” instead of “q0”, as in my answer?

Comment: Yes, there is no error via xcrun (as you showed). But when building it in Xcode - i've got an error

Comment: Just created an empty Xcode project with no changes, pasted    __asm__("":::"v0"); and there and the same error

Comment: Ok, obviously it’s not “the same error there”, because that expression doesn’t contain “q0” anywhere.  What build command is being invoked by Xcode?  What is the actual error produced?

Comment: (Psychic debugging:) You’re getting an error for “v0” when Xcode tries to build your now-arm64 assembly for armv7 (or armv7s).  You need to have separate assembly for arm32 and arm64.  They are different ISAs.

Comment: Oh, that's better now

Comment: But still I can't find the register list for the arm64. Can you provide a link or smth like that? If the substitution for q0 is v0, then what is the substitution for d0 ?

Comment: Except for loads and stores (and a few other things), you don’t use sub-register names anymore with arm64 NEON assembly.  More generally, I don’t know if there is a published guide for arm64 inline assembler with clang.  It would be worth filing a bug report to ask for one.

Comment: v0 is d0 as well. The bit width isn't determined by the register names anymore, but in instruction suffixes instead. I just wonder why someone should bother with inline assembly when he can program in native assembly though. Anyway, lots of work await ahead for you converting your assembly code to AARCH64. Not only the ISA, but the syntax is completely different. Good luck!

Comment: Here is what you have been looking for. You might have to sign in at ARM.com for downloading though : https://silver.arm.com/download/ARM_and_AMBA_Architecture/AR100-DA-70501-r0p0-00eac5/ARMv8_ISA_PRD03-GENC-010197-30-0.pdf

Comment: Inline assembler: the architecture-independence of assembly, combined with the stability and documentation of intrinsics.  (There are a few good reasons to use it, in fairness).

Comment: Agreed. But there are more good reasons not to use it, at least not without knowing exactly what's on the stake.

Comment: Hello  @StephenCanon, i need your help in the error unknown register name 'q0' in asm. Can you help me ?