# iOS - Will ASM code run on armv7/armv7s/arm64?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, assembly, arm64

I'm trying to figure out if the `ASM` code for the function `neon_asm_convert()` in the example [here](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/02/A-VERY-FAST-BGRA-TO-GRAYSCALE-CONVERSION-ON-IPHONE/) will run on all `armv7/armv7s/arm64` processors (ie., `iPhone 4S/5/5S`).

Unfortunately, I don't own all of these devices, so a simple run-test is out of the question.
However, I'm developing an app (testing it only using `armv7`) which uses the `__asm__()` from the `neon_asm_convert()`, and I would like to find out if the `ASM` code will also run on `arm64`.

I think I read that `ASM` code that runs on `armv7/armv7s` won't run on `arm64` but I can't seem to find that reference anymore.

Does anyone have any pointers that cold help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not going to run on `arm64`. As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19984325/1806873) answer says:

> arm64 is a new ISA. The actual NEON instructions and register layout are entirely new. You will need to re-write or adapt assembly code for the new architecture.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomer said, no.  arm64 is a new architecture with a new instruction syntax and register layout.

However, fast implementations of this sort of colorspace conversion are available in the SDK as part of the Accelerate.framework.  Except in special circumstances, you shouldn’t need to write your own assembly code for this.  Specifically, you can use the vImageConvert_AnyToAny function, which provides high-performance implementations of this and many, many other common conversions that work on all of the architectures that Apple ships (armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386, x86_64).