# Unknown register name "r0" in asm

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm in the process of converting an iOS 32-bit app to a 64-bit binary. I was able to build and test the app fine on the simulator and device however when I build for distribution to the App Store I get an error:

```
Unknown register name "r0" in asm
```

The debugger points to this line:

```
    VFP_VECTOR_LENGTH_ZERO
                          : "=r" (result), "=r" (m2)
                          : "r" (m1), "0" (result), "1" (m2)
                          : "r0", "cc", "memory", VFP_CLOBBER_S0_S31
                          );
```

I saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984307/unknown-register-name-q0-in-asm-arm64) however i'm unsure what the solution is.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're gonna have to rewrite the assembly for arm64.